# Asking if posible inserting primary key in related data if related data is null upon inserring

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I just wandering i insert my data in relation data i tried to not insert in the related model that model. the result is null and doesnt have a key save in db.

its one-to-one relation

C# ef core

i tried this in json

```
{
  testingName: "123231",
  testingRelatedData: {
    testingNameRelated: "asdasd"
 }
}
```

and code is a normal way of adding in context.

```
class model {
  public int modelid {get; set;}
  public string testingName  {get; set;}
  public virtual testingNameRelated testingNameRelated { get; set; }
}
class testingNameRelated{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string testingNameRelated{get; set;}

  public model model {get; set;}
  public int modelid {get; set;}
}

context.testing.add(model)
```

thanks